# Create Power BI Measure based on the value in the column of the current table for each row and selected values from the slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a Measure in the table based on a calculation with the value in the another column and selected values from slicer.

`Table "MyTab:"`

| DataType | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | Product 1 | 100 |
| Type1 | Product 2 | 200 |
| Type1 | Product 3 | 300 |
| Type2 | Product 1 | 50 |
| Type2 | Product 2 | 60 |

First, "MyMeasure" should use the value for the "DataType" column, so for each row I need to use value from that column. I'm trying to use this code, but it doesn`t work properly:

```
MyMeasure = maxx('MyTab', 'MyTab'[DataType])
```

Also, I tried this:

```
MyMeasure = CALCULATE(min( 
     'MyTad'[DataType]), 
    FILTER ('MyTad', 'MyTad'[DataType]="Type1"))
```

So, I need to get this table:

| DataType | Product | Amount | MyMeasure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | Product 1 | 100 | Type1 |
| Type1 | Product 2 | 200 | Type1 |
| Type1 | Product 3 | 300 | Type1 |
| Type2 | Product 1 | 50 | Type2 |
| Type2 | Product 2 | 60 | Type2 |

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want a measure which simply returns the DataType entries for each row?

Comment: @JosWoolley yes, for this simplified example. Add new measure "MyMeasure" with value from "DataType" column for each row

Comment: Either there's something you're not sharing with us, else you can use simply `MyMeasure = MIN(MyTab[DataType])`

Comment: @JosWoolley It worket in the table visualisation without aggregation, but did not work in Line chart vis with aggregation. I added DateType to the x-axis also and seems to be working now. Thanks.